# struct intitialization notation not working with heap allocated storage

Tags: c, gcc

With gcc (GCC) 4.4.6 , I try to compile this program -

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 
  4 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  5 {
  6 
  7     struct B {
  8         int i;
  9         char ch;
 10     };
 11 
 12     struct B *ptr;
 13 
 14     ptr = (struct B*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct B));
 15 
 16     *ptr = {
 17         .i = 10,
 18         .ch = 'c',
 19     };
 20 
 21     printf("%d,%c\n", ptr->i, ptr->ch);
 22 
 23     return 0;
 24 }
 25 

$ make
gcc -g -Wall -o test test.c 
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:16: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*ptr = {
   .i = 10,
   .ch = 'c',
};
```

This usage is called **designated initializer**, as the name implies, it's only used to *initialize* struct or arrays, but what you are trying to do is *assigning*.

The correct usage of designated initializer:

```
strcut B foo = {.i = 10, .ch = 'c'};
```

To assign the struct, you still need to use:

```
 ptr->i = 10;
 ptr->ch = 'c';
```

**EDIT**: Or you can use a compound literal like in @Andrey T's answer:

```
*ptr = (struct B) {
  .i = 10,
  .ch = 'c',
};
```

Comment: May be he still need a example of  **designated initializer**

Comment: @LidongGuo Example added, but it's not possible with a heap object.

Comment: Well, "impossible" is string word considering that what the OP is trying to do can be done through *compound literal*, as shown in my answer. Conceptually, of course, it is not the same thing, but practically it does what the OP wants it to do with only minor change in syntax.

Comment: @AndreyT Right, a compound literal is a better choice. I edited my words. Upvote for you.

Answer (score 3):

"Struct initialization notation" you are talking about uses the term "initialization" for a reason: it is intended to be used in *initialization* contexts. What you are trying to do is not initialization at all. It is assignment. This syntax will not immediately work in assignment contexts.

In order to still make use of this convenient syntax you have to create another struct of the same type, initialize it using this syntax, and then copy that struct to your struct by using assignment. For example

```
ptr = calloc(1, sizeof *ptr);

const struct B INIT = {
  .i = 10,
  .ch = 'c',
};

*ptr = INIT;
```

This already achieves what you are trying to do, but you can make the above more compact by using the *compound literal* feature of C language

```
ptr = calloc(1, sizeof *ptr);

*ptr = (struct B) {
  .i = 10,
  .ch = 'c',
};
```

Basically, the latter code sample is probably what you are looking for. However, note that conceptually this is still not *initialization*. It is an assignment, which creates a temporary object of type `struct B` and then assigns it to your `*ptr` object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize (allocate a value to) a dynamically allocated structure, you will need to use a C99 compound literal on the RHS of the assignment:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct B { int i; char ch; };
    struct B *ptr = (struct B*) calloc(1, sizeof(struct B));
    *ptr = (struct B){ .i = 10, .ch = 'c', };

    printf("%d,%c\n", ptr->i, ptr->ch);
    return 0;
}
```

The notation uses a cast and an initializer instead of just an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

In a structure initializer, specify the name of a field to initialize with ‘.`fieldname` =’ before the element value. For example, given the following structure,

struct point { int x, y; };

the following initialization

struct point p = { .y = value1, .x = value2};

is equivalent to

struct point p = { value1, value2};

Another syntax that has the same meaning,‘fieldname:’, as shown here:

struct point p = { y: value2, x: value1};

The ‘[`index`]’ or ‘.`fieldname`’ is known as a designator. Below code will work. For pointer `YU Hao` has told..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

     struct B {
         int i;
         char ch;
     } ;

    struct B name = {
         .i = 10,
         .ch = 'c',
     };

     printf("%d,%c\n", name.i, name.ch);

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*ptr = {
   .i = 10,
   .ch = 'c',
};
```

This usage is called designated initializer and is used only while initialisation not for assignment. As far as i know its not for a pointer, as only 4 bytes are allocated for any pointer.